# Магия в Java Substring

Tags: java, строки, подстрока

Столкнулся со следующим непониманием, при переносе кода на c# под java.
Нужно вытащить из строки символов подстроку, взять, начиная с некоторой k-й позиции n-символов. Собственно, код:

```
str = "((15+3)+14/2+(7*2)+3^2+(12+(7*2)))";
System.out.println(str.substring(27, 5));
```

Для меня, как человека немного знакомого с шарпом, код вполне понятный и логичный. В строке 33 символа, собственно, мне необходимо получить подстроку с 27 - символ ( по 32, символ ). Но в результате я получаю ошибку OutOfBoundException. Причем даже, если захочу взять с 10 позиции 3 символа. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) java, метод `substring` принимает 2 параметра: начальный индекс - откуда начинать вырезать, и конечный индекс - до куда вырезать.

```
substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

метод `substring` принимает начало и конец, а не начала и количество символов

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, я просто очень плохо знаю java. Нужно указать позиции символов в массиве явно, а не кол-во элементов, которые я хотел бы взять как в c#.

Answer (score 0):

Вывести последние 5 символов поможет код:

```
System.out.println(str.substring(str.length()-5, str.length()));
```

Comment: "с 27й позиции 5 символов" ≠ "последние 5 символов".

Comment: Да. Я был невнимателеный.